# Generate number of related records based on a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I admit, the title of the question is odd, but I don't know how to express it better.

I'll try to explain what I need.

I have a table which contains number of scheduled inspections for a contract, and contract start date

e.g.

```
ContractID    Start Date     No. Inspections
     1         2014/1/1             4
     2         2014/1/1             3
```

What I need is to create a select that returns a row for each scheduled inspection and its scheduled start dates, e.g. :

```
ContractID    Start Date     Inspection No     Inspection Start date
     1         2014/1/1             1              2014/1/1
     1         2014/1/1             2              2014/1/3
     1         2014/1/1             3              2014/1/6
     1         2014/1/1             4              2014/1/9
     2         2014/1/1             1              2014/1/1
     2         2014/1/1             2              2014/1/4
     2         2014/1/1             3              2014/1/8
```

I can use a while loop in a SP to generate a temp table to join with main table, but I'm wondering if there is another way based only on select.
(Please ignore the Inspection Start Date column in result, that was just to make the result easier to understand - what I need are the first three columns actually)

Thank you

Comment: How does that extra column make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `master.spt_values` if the numbers never get too big:

```
select t.contractid, t.startdate, n.number as inspectionnum
from table t join
     master.spt_values n
     on n.number <= t.numinspections;
```